# Max integer with same strings, in a red black tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I have a tree with a set of numbers, where each number has 2 strings associated :a and b. So the structure looks like:

> a-number-b

for each node.

I want to get the maximum number in the tree where a=b in O(log n) worst case run time.

My approach:
Tried a Red black tree. This has O(log n) if the number is in right sub-tree.
But O(n) if the number is in left sub tree.

Cant use regular BST, as for worst case, it has O(n) as the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to maintain two trees; one where a == b and one where a != b. For most functions you will probably need to call in to both trees but this will end up as the same big-O complexity since 2*O(log n) -> O(log n).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if for each subtree you stored the max possible value among the nodes of the tree.

For a given tree, the max you require can be read off the root.

During insertion/deletion/rotation, this property can be maintained in O(log n) time.

There is a chapter called *Augmenting Data Structures* in *Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al* (commonly called the CLR book).  on this.

I suggest you read it. The relevant theorem is Theorem 14.1 which states

> Let `f` be a field that augments a red-black tree `T` of `n` nodes and
>   suppose that the contents of `f` for a node `x` can be computed using only
>   information in nodes `x`, `left(x)` and `right(x)`, including `f(left(x))` and
>   `f(right(x))`. Then we can maintain the values of `f` in all nodes of `T`
>   during insertion and deletion without asymptotically affecting the
>   `O(log n)` performance of these operations.

left(x) is the left child of x, etc.

For you case, define `g(node)` to be `node.number` if `node.a == node.b`, and `-infinity` otherwise.

Define `f(x)` to be `max f(left(x)), f(right(x)), g(x)`.